# How Can I calculate value by percentage in python?

Tags: python

I want to calculate 67% of 947 or any dynamic number how can I do it with Python?

I did (self.discount / self.price)*100.0

expected: 647.89

but 6.928645294725956

Comment: `new_price = 200*0.6` or `new_price = 200*(1 - 0.6)`?

Comment: self.discount / self.price is not how discounts or math work.

Comment: Thx @timgeb for this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

67% = 67/100 = 0.67

So `new_price = old_price * Discount_in_percent/100`